# Reading and writing images to an SQLite DB for iPhone use

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, nsdata

I've set up a SQLite DB that currently reads and writes `NSString`s perfectly. I also want to store an image in the database and recall it later. I've read up a bit on using `NSData` and encoding the image, but I'm not entirely sure what the syntax is for what I want to do. Any code snippets or examples would be greatly appreciated.

My current process goes like this:
`UIImagePickerController` -> User Chooses Image from Photos -> chosenImage is set to instance of `UIImageView` -> **Now I want to take this image and store it in the DB**

I should mention this call will eventually be replaced with a call to a remote server. Not sure if this makes a difference as far as performance goes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option (and generally preferred when working in SQL) is to write the image to a file on the system and store the path (or some other kind of identifier) in the database.

Comment: I'm really at a loss as to why anyone would store the binary in the DB. Seems nuts to me. So I think the metadata in the DB is the best case.

Comment: Can you show me a code example for something like this? I can see how saving out to a file could be beneficial.

Comment: after a few days of googling. I've realized and executed this idea. I'll post some code if anyone needs it.

Comment: [link](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html) - comparing performance sqlite external vs. internal blob storage by sqlite team themselves.

Answer (score 31):

You'll need to convert the UIImage hosted within your UIImageView into a binary BLOB for storage in SQLite.  To do that, you can use the following:

```
NSData *dataForImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cachedImage);
sqlite3_bind_blob(yourSavingSQLStatement, 2, [dataForImage bytes], [dataForImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

This will generate a PNG representation of your image, store it in an NSData instance, and then bind the bytes from the NSData as a BLOB for the second argument in your SQL query.  Use UIImageJPEGRepresentation in the above to store in that format, if you like.   You will need to have a BLOB column added to the appropriate table in your SQLite database.

To retrieve this image, you can use the following:

```
NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(yourLoadingSQLStatement, 2) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(yourLoadingSQLStatement, 2)];       
self.cachedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:dataForCachedImage];
[dataForCachedImage release];
```

Comment: Thanks Brad! I'll give this a try later this afternoon. Looks like it may do the trick though.

Comment: I realized this isn't want I wanted to do. Saving the file to a URL on the server is a better way to go.

Comment: If that works best for application, then that's the way to go.  I've stored images in the database when I wanted a single file that I could bundle in an application which would hold some starter data.  It made the filesystem a little cleaner.

Comment: won't blob slow down the performance? i dont think it is a good solution

Answer (score 9):

Apple's recommendation is not to store BLOB's in SQLite databases that are bigger than ~2 kilobytes.

SQLite organizes databases into pages. Each page is 4 kilobytes in size.  When you read data from the SQLite database file it loads these pages into an internal page cache.  On the iPhone I think this cache defaults to 1 megabyte in size.  This makes reading adjacent records very fast because they will probably be in the page cache already.

When SQLite reads your database record into memory it reads the entire record and all of the pages that it occupies.  So if your record contains a BLOB, it could occupy many pages and you will be ejecting existing pages from the cache and replacing them with your BLOB record's pages.

This isn't so bad if you're just scanning through and loading all your BLOBS to do something with them (display them for example).  But if say you did a query where you just wanted to get some data that is in the same row as the BLOB this query would be much slower than if the record did not contain the large BLOB.

So at a minimum you should store your BLOB data in a separate table.  Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE blobs ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data BLOB );
CREATE TABLE photos ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, blob_id INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY(blob_id) REFERENCES blobs(id) );
```

Or better yet, store the BLOB data as files outside of the SQLite database.

Note that it may be possible to tweak the page cache size with [SQL PRAGMA statements](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) (if you're not using CoreData).

Comment: Where does Apple recommend that?

Answer (score 2):

Writing Image to SQLite DB

```
if(myImage != nil){
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    sqlite3_bind_blob(update_stmtement, 6, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);    
    }
    else {
        sqlite3_bind_blob(update_stmtement, 6, nil, -1, NULL);
    }
```

Reading From SQLite DB:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(init_statement, 6) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(init_statement, 6)];
        if(data == nil)
            NSLog(@"No image found.");
        else
            self.pictureImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to compress the image and store it in the database or file system. If you don't care about the resolution of the image you can go ahead and even resize the image by using :

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);  
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];   
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

After that you can use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` for jpeg images with a value of "0" for maximum compression. Or you can use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` for png images

Answer (score 0):

you should first write image on file system. and then take the image path and store that image path(URL) as TEXT in sqlite.