# Save Web Images to Sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimage

I have an application which sets an web image to the background of the homepage.From next time it loads the homepage background from web as my application stores just the name with the address.This is my code:

```
Sqlite *sqlite = [[Sqlite alloc] init];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, SUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.db"];

if (![sqlite open:writableDBPath])
    return;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mmabigshow.com/app/admin/ring_girl_demo.php"];
NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *string1 = @"";

string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE mma_bg_image SET image='%@' where id='1';", greeting];
```

What I want to do is, that when I set some image as background it should be stored as UIImage object in the local database of the phone so that it will load faster from next time onwards.
Should I use Sqlite? Please paste me the total source code of the process.

Comment: Who's Brad? And why must the poor guy paste you the total source code of the process?

Comment: Would it be so vain, to think this question is about me?

Answer (score 11):

Why don't you just store the image on the filesystem?
Of course you could store it into the DB but it wouldn't make your app faster.
You would have to encode the file using NSData before inserting it and decode it before displaying it.
I would store the file on the filesystem and keep just the path in the DB.

**Edit:**
  Yours truly, Brad

Answer (score 4):

I provide code for storing UIImages to, and loading them from, an SQLite database in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use/643819#643819).

Sincerely, Another Brad