# Store png/pdf file in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, blob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading and writing images to an SQLite DB for iPhone use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use)

How to store pdf,png file in sqlite.

is this possible to store pdf and png file?

Please help me out.

if you have any idea please share with me.

Thanks you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a BLOB data type so I guess you can:

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 1):

You can store a PDF or PNG file in a BLOB field.

first create the table

```
create table Blubber ( PK int primary key , BITSINK blob );
```

then use insert to add the data.

```
insert into Blubber (PK,BITSINK) 
values (1, 'your blob goes here, best to use bind variables though!');
```

Tell us what language you are using for advice how to use bind variable.

**EDIT** just saw this is taged iPhone, the language would be the appropriate C dialect (objective c??)