# sqlite3 insert and read BLOB data in database

Tags: select, insert, sqlite, blob

I need to read and write BLOB data to a database. Here is my structure table

```
    #define CREATE_TABLE_USERS_SQL "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %@ ( \
UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, \
Name VARCHAR(50), \
Image BLOB);"
```

How can I insert it into database, and then retrieve from it?

Environment: iPhone SDK 4.1 SQLite3 database.

This code fails:

```
        NSData * buf2 = [[NSData alloc] init];
        sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 5);
        buf2 = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 5);
        user.image = [UIImage imageWithData: buf2];
```

Comment: This question is asking the same thing as yours, and the answers there should address your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use

Answer (score 13):

Thanx all!! With yours help I'v solved problem and want to share results for future beginners like I am.)

```
-(void) addToDB
{
    NSLog(@"\nCreating db");
    NSString *str = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Images (image1 BLOB);";
    int res = SQLITE_ERROR;


    res = sqlite3_open([@"aa.sql" UTF8String], &database);
    res = sqlite3_exec(database, [str UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_stmt *updStmt =nil; 

    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO Images (image1) VALUES (?);";
    res = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updStmt, NULL);

    if(res!= SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement:%s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"flower.png"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];

    res = sqlite3_bind_blob(updStmt, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length] , SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if((res = sqlite3_step(updStmt)) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while updating: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_reset(updStmt);
    } 

    res = sqlite3_reset(updStmt);
    res = sqlite3_close(database);
}

-(void) readFromDB
{
    NSLog(@"\nReading from db");

    NSString *query = @"SELECT image1 from Images";
    int res = SQLITE_ERROR;
    int len = 0;

    res = sqlite3_open([@"aa.sql" UTF8String], &database);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    res = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil);

    if (res == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            len = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0);
            NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0) length: len];           


            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];

            self.view1.image = img;

        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    res = sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting,this code works well.but when i change the name of the image from "flower.png" to some other like "xyz.png" then it display the previous image in imageview so can you point out the reason.......

Comment: maby you need to go to appropriate record in database first, and only then read image from it, and now it always takes first record. try that, I really don't remember it was a year ago.

Comment: in NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement:%@", sqlite3_errmsg(database)); %s formatting should be used

Comment: constant SQLITE_BLOB is wrongly used in sqlite3_bind_blob call. SQLITE_TRANSIENT or SQLITE_STATIC should be used there. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

Comment: Be careful  with the use of SQLITE_TRANSIENT usage. Depending on your case it may cause a BAD_ACCESS error. This was my situation until I changed it to SQLITE_STATIC.

Comment: what language is this in? I don't see it listed anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Apart from choosing your client or programming interface, usage does not differ from any other string field.

---

[Update] I haven't had the luck to develop for the iPhone yet, but I believe it's the same as any other SELECT or INSERT query. Make sure to encode the BLOB and enclose it with single apostrophes (`'`) like strings.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `fmdb` by Gus Mueller *et al*, of Flying Meat? http://flyingmeat.com/

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

If you find `fmdb` useful, go and buy one of the excellents apps of Flying Meat. VoodooPad or Acron.

Answer (score 0):

//-----insert IMAGE

```
  - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)theImage
 {

  if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&myDatabase)==SQLITE_OK)
  {    
    NSString *insertProgrammeSql = @"INSERT INTO imageTable (imageName) VALUES (?)";

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, [insertProgrammeSql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage);

         sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    sqlite3_step(statement);
}
  sqlite3_close(myDatabase);
//  return YES;    
}   


  }
```

//--------get image

```
   -(UIImage *)getImage

    {

    UIImage *image = nil;


if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&myDatabase)==SQLITE_OK)
{   

NSString *selectSql = @"SELECT image FROM imageTable";

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, [selectSql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0);
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0 ) length:length];

    image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];



  sqlite3_finalize(statement);

  }
     sqlite3_close(myDatabase);
  }
 return image;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> This code fails:
>
> ```
>    NSData * buf2 = [[NSData alloc] init];
>    sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 5);
>    buf2 = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 5);
>    user.image = [UIImage imageWithData: buf2];
> ```

You are calling the SQLite functions in the correct order. According to the SQLite docs:

> The safest and easiest to remember policy is to invoke these routines
>   in one of the following ways:
>
> - sqlite3_column_text() followed by sqlite3_column_bytes()
> - sqlite3_column_blob() followed by sqlite3_column_bytes()
> - sqlite3_column_text16() followed by sqlite3_column_bytes16()
>
> In other words, you should call sqlite3_column_text(),
>   sqlite3_column_blob(), or sqlite3_column_text16() first to force the
>   result into the desired format, then invoke sqlite3_column_bytes() or
>   sqlite3_column_bytes16() to find the size of the result. Do not mix
>   calls to sqlite3_column_text() or sqlite3_column_blob() with calls to
>   sqlite3_column_bytes16(), and do not mix calls to
>   sqlite3_column_text16() with calls to sqlite3_column_bytes().

However, `buff2` is an integer, not a data pointer. `sqlite3_column_bytes` tells you how many bytes are in the blob.