# Save blob'type in database

Tags: iphone, ios

I want save data of iOS, `NSData` to the database of `FMDB`, such  as:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://pic17.nipic.com/20111023/7050178_121536234000_2.jpg"];
NSData *date=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSString *img=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into name(picture) values('%@')",date ];
BOOL judge1=[self.database executeUpdate:img];
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: are you getting any error or exception?

Comment: saving image data in database is not fair thing,because it takes much size better you can save path of the image in DB.

Comment: don't get! but don't display

Comment: I want to change imgae to data of ios'NSData,then save the data,It's right???

Comment: As @Mak said, you should save image locally in your application and then just save the path of that image in database, not whole image data.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
NSLog(@"\nCreating db");
NSString *str = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Images (image1 BLOB);";
int res = SQLITE_ERROR;


res = sqlite3_open([@"aa.sql" UTF8String], &database);
res = sqlite3_exec(database, [str UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

sqlite3_stmt *updStmt =nil; 

const char *sql = "INSERT INTO Images (image1) VALUES (?);";
res = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updStmt, NULL);

if(res!= SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement:%s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"flower.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];

res = sqlite3_bind_blob(updStmt, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length] , SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

if((res = sqlite3_step(updStmt)) != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSLog(@"Error while updating: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_reset(updStmt);
} 

res = sqlite3_reset(updStmt);
res = sqlite3_close(database);
```

Refer : [sqlite3 insert and read BLOB data in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215505/sqlite3-insert-and-read-blob-data-in-database)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did all these steps.

```
FMDatabase *databse = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"Path"];
[database open];  
NSURL *url=[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://pic17.nipic.com/20111023/7050178_121536234000_2.jpg"];  
NSData *date=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
NSString *img=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO name (picture) values('%@')",date ];  
BOOL judge1;  
judge1=[database executeUpdate:img];
```