# SQLLite query WHERE with NSNumber gives BAD_ACCESS error while processing params

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsnumber

I'm having a problem with inserting an int to an SQLite database for my iOS app. When I select it, it's always zero.

I'm creating this table:

```
CREATE TABLE followedCategory(id TEXT(256) primary key, title TEXT(256), img BLOB, following INTEGER)
```

The last param (`following`) is causing the problems. I insert records with this piece of code:

```
DatabaseRecord *rec = [database query:@"INSERT INTO followedCategory VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4)" params:category.categoryId, category.title, UIImagePNGRepresentation(category.image), [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil];
[rec next];
```

When I query the table with this:

```
DatabaseRecord *rec = [database query:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followedCategory WHERE following = ?1" params:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil];
[rec next];

return [rec intAtCol:0];
```

I always get zero results back. When I run this:

```
DatabaseRecord *recTest = [database query:@"SELECT following FROM followedCategory LIMIT 2"];
[recTest next];
NSLog(@"First following is %i", [recTest intAtCol:0]);
[recTest next];
NSLog(@"Second following is %i", [recTest intAtCol:1]);
```

I get back this in the logs:

```
2014-01-29 10:24:58.595 App[1940:60b] First following is 0
2014-01-29 10:24:58.596 App[1940:60b] Second following is 0
```

I guess the insert query is causing the problems as , but I can't figure out why. By the way, I'm using an `NSNumber` because the Database class converts it to an int, can't pass an int to the `DatabaseRecord`.

Anyone a suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that Inserting of BLOB may cause that error. Just refere this below link may help you lot.
[sqlite3 insert and read BLOB data in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215505/sqlite3-insert-and-read-blob-data-in-database)

Comment: But the BLOB never caused a problem before I added the column following, so I figured it must be something else..