# Objective C, How to store UIImage

Tags: objective-c

I want to store an image from imagePickerController delegate method... I know that the image returned is huge so I will resize it. I have used SQLite for data persistency but don't have any idea how I can store the image...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIImagePNGRepresentation()` takes a `UIImage` as an argument and returns an `NSData` object (the image in PNG format.) You can then write that to disk/a database/wherever. When it's time to get the image back, pull the data from its source and use `-[UIImage initWithData:]` to reconstitute it.