# How to take a picture and save in SQLite database on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have a camera application in which when I click on the camera button the camera opens and user can take picture from camera or from photo-library.

I have done the camera part such that when user clicks on the button the camera opens and he can take a picture. The problem is the picture the user has taken from the camera must be saved into SQLite database. I am stuck in this part. Could anybody help me on how to save image taken from camera ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading and writing images to an SQLite DB for iPhone use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `UIImagePickerController`, you can get the image in its `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method. The image you get is an `UIImage` object.

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

Now `NSData` has a method `bytes` which returns `void*`. This will point to a C type array which should play well with SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a blob type data field in your database and then save the byte data into that column. But it is a bad practice to save images in database. Instead you can save images in documents directory unless it is very necessary to save images in database.

Answer (score 0):

Now when you opens the camera, you implement the following method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {

[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

in the above method add the following code :--

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1);
```

then call the method of saving data to database.

Make sure you take the field type as blob in database.

Hope it helps.....

Comment: hi i want if i capture picture by camera then how i save picture in database can u help me what the code for it

Comment: I am also looking for same, can you provide the code to save capture image in database, it's help me a lot, it's is the main part my application and i am not able to do it.