# Where are images stored on the phone when taking a photo programatically in an app?

Tags: ios, photo

I am trying to learn more about how photo capture works on iOS. I want to ensure that if an application is used to take a picture, the image is only handled by the application and is not stored elsewhere in a camera roll, temp file, etc. Ideally, the photo is taken and then the application can implement encryption, etc. to ensure that the photo is stored confidentially (sensitive document "scanning" as the scenario).

What are the security considerations in this scenario, the user will be trained not to use the system camera application and to only use the "scanning" functionality via the app. Using public APIs, will any temp files or automatic images be stored outside of my control, and how could I deal with those? This is not clearly specified in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406-SW1), and I am afraid there might be security/privacy leaks if not fully understood.

I see how to store the image in [SQLite db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186224/how-to-take-a-picture-and-save-in-sqlite-database-on-ios), but would there be any other file system artifacts left over?

Answer (score 0):

If they are photos, you can have **NSData** for those photos as a final result. Then you can save the data of the photo in a directory inside your application.

Best place to store that kind of data/files in **Application Support Directory.**

```
NSString *appSupportDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *photoPath = [appSupportDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo1.png"];

UIImage *image; //image you got from the camera inside your app

NSData *photoData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[photoData writeToFile:photoPath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented. No one but the devs at Apple know for sure if a photo taken with the `UIImagePickerController` results in some temp file somewhere on the filesystem.

Ignoring the possibility of some temp file for the moment, the photo is not stored in the photo library or camera roll at all. It is up to your app to do what you will with the image sent to the `UIImagePickerController` delegate method.

If a temp file is stored somewhere, the only way it could be accessed is with a jailbroken device. If you really need to be 100% sure that no temp file exists for any period of time, you are going to need a jailbroken device and you will need to scan the filesystem as your app makes use of the image picker.