# How add thousands of images in iphone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have to add thousands of images in my iphone project.

What is best way to flow for it?

I think putting images into bundle is not a good way.

Please suggest me

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 3):

You have two options, IMO: either you store the images in the app bundle, or you download them from a website.

I don't see any problems with storing the images in the bundle. The bundle will be larger and take time to download (and it will be downloadable only via WIFI, not 3G). There are many apps around whose bundle is 200+MB...

if you have some `NSData` (say, downloaded through NSURLConnection) that you want to store to the documents folder, do:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
 NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory 
 NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filname.ext"];
 [nsData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

For a way to store to sqlite, see this [S.O. article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use). Anyway, as I said in a comment, I would not see much sense to it; you don't use a DB to store file, that's what a file system is meant for; you use a DB to store data that you want to search, sort, join, etc... Anywau, it could be ok to store in sqlite the paths to the images.

Comment: I agree with sergio, i know of an app which has HD videos and the size is about 800 mb. So when there is no restriction, one can decide the tradeoff which is basically the download time for first time installation.

Comment: actually interviewer ask me this question... I have to store in locally in app .. but not in bundle

Comment: then you are left with the download option, so you can store them locally in the "Documents" folder...

Comment: well .. can you tell me how we store locally in document folder

Comment: Better to store them under Library in case you want to prevent user access.

Comment: you can store binary data so sqlite but I don't see the point. what could make more sense is storing the paths to the images in sqlite...

Answer (score 0):

How big are those images? If they are too big, it's not advisable to put all of them in bundle. As you dont want to have a big binary just cause of the images!

Maybe you can stream (through HTTP) the images on demand...

Comment: actually interviewer ask me this question... I have to store in locally in app .. but not in bundle