# How to store images in the sqlite database in iphone

Tags: iphone, database, ipad, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading and writing images to an SQLite DB for iPhone use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use)

How to store a images file in database in blob type in sqlite database and how to retrieve a image from the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

save image in your nsdocument directory. in database save the path of this image.  this is a good approach. if u save blob in data base database will so heavy. it take time to load.

Answer (score 0):

First convert image into NSData 
Then NSData into bytes
Then store that bytes...
Sorry I don't know the method that should be called, because I use core data which is far better than sqlite c api

Comment: Don't mind but `core data is far better than sqlite c api` in terms of ? There should be clear distinction when you say like that.

Comment: There is only one answer for it i.e www.google.com
:) :) :) 
but really it's methods are written in objective c and insertion, deletion and updating is very easy. Moreover core data uses sqlite as db.

Comment: Lets say if you have 10000 rows and you want to update only single row based on ID what you have to do in core data and sqlite db ? You should not underestimate like that. Each part is available we have to use it wisely what is best. Think abt that

Comment: To answer that you have to load all the rows in memory for core data whereas it can be done only on single query update. Hope you get my point

Comment: I dont think till now I have to update 10000 rows at a time... it mobile application not a web application. Anyways it depends upon the you application. In you case sqlite c api is better... I don't want to argue.... :/

Comment: Did you read my comment at all ? I am asking that If you want to update single row out of 10000 rows you have to load all the rows into memory if you are using core data and with sqlite you can update with single statement.

Comment: @Jennis - No, you don't have to load it all into memory with Core Data either. Just fetch the entity that you need (note: entity, not row) change it and save it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an Objective-C sqlite wrapper such as [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Then you can pass an NSData handle from UIImagePNGRepresentation() into the wrapper as a blob.

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
NSData *rawImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myUIImage);
sqlite3_bind_blob(mySavedSQLStatement, 2, [rawImage bytes], [rawImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```