# How can I read image as binary  data from database  using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

```
NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
NSString *aImageUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
```

I want to read `aImageUrl` as binary. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading and writing images to an SQLite DB for iPhone use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [BLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob.html) (Binary Large OBject) if you want to store the actual image from that URL.

```
//Storage
UIImage *image = ...; //Retrieve image from URL
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStatement, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], NULL);

//Retrieval
const void *data = sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 1);
int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 1);
UIImage *retrieved = [UIImage imageWithData:
                          [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:length]];
```