# Can't display image from sqlite database (blob) in iphone

Tags: ios, database, image, sqlite, blob

I'm trying to display image from my sqlite database (as a blob), it knows that the image file is there by displaying the length of the image and the NSLog:"Image FOUND", but it doesn't load the image in the imageview. I've tried those many examples from stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use/643819#643819) and more else but still no issue.Thanks in advance guys. Here is what I got so far:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement1;

NSString *querySQL1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT picture FROM table1 WHERE var = %f", variable];

const char *query_statement1 = [querySQL1 UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, query_statement1, -1, &statement1, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    if (sqlite3_step(statement1) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {

    int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement1, 0);

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement1, 0) length:length];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        NSLog(@"Length : %d", [data length]);

        if(data == nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"No image found.");
            }

        else
            {
                NSLog(@"image FOUND .");
                myImageView.image = image;       
            }   
    }

}
```

Comment: just because data != nil doesn't mean that it contains valid image data (i.e. a PNG or JPG image) that [UIImage imageWithData] will handle.  Check if (image == nil) instead.  If you see nil, then look into the contents of your data.

Comment: just tried that out and it returned : image FOUND but still displays nothing in the imageview.

Comment: It could be tons of things. As CSmith says, it could be that what you retrieved from the database was not a valid image. In addition to testing to see if `data` was `nil`, check to see if `image` was `nil`. If that's `nil`, then the problem is in the data in the database. If it's not `nil`, then it's something else (e.g. maybe the `myImageView` is `nil` or its `frame` is such that you cannot see it).

Comment: Got it worked guys!!! The problem was about the two things that you both mentioned. It's working fine now. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you think your findings will be useful to future users, [post an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) outlining what it was. Or, better, invite CSmith to post an answer. If, though, the solution is unlikely to be useful to future users (e.g. it was just some silly mistake), then maybe just delete this question

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite3 *dataname1;

if (sqlite3_open([datapath UTF8String],&dataname1) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sqlStatement;

    sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM photography_tips";


    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataname1, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            // Read the data from the result row
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 2)];
            [tipimage addObject:data];

        }

    }
NSLog(@"%@", tiptittle);
}
```

then add the following code in cellforrowatindexpath method

```
 NSData *data= (NSData *) [tipimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```